# Can I provide RGB hex strings in an Excel worksheet for pie chart colors without using code?

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

Like user1813558 in his question ["Change the pie chart colors"](https://superuser.com/q/516507/166855) I would like to choose the colors that Excel uses for a pie chart (indeed for any chart) as I need them to be consistent with other data visualizations we have carefully produced so that a color-blind team mate can still join in data trawl sessions. But rather than write code I would like to do it in the Excel sheet. Is there any way I can put the color data down in the Excel worksheet, for example as a column of RGB hex strings like 7DFF7D, and point the chart at that column for its color choice?

Comment: Perhaps the approach outlined in [this link](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/) would help?

Comment: I don't think that is specifying the colors used. Can you be more specific about where in the approach he applies colors specified in the data?

Comment: Without using VBA I don't think it would be possible. There's no option in the UI to specify the color based on Cell values.

Comment: Thanks Brad. If you add this as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would like to do is not possible without code.

The following VBA function can be used to set colors based on cell values for a pie chart in the active worksheet. The color values can be in an N rows x 3 columns range of decimal RGB values or an N rows x 1 column range of 6 digit hex values (where the hex number is a set of three 2-digit hex values in RGB order).

The function requires two arguments: a reference to the range of color values (A1:A5, for example) and the name of the pie chart. The chart name can either be a default name (such as "Chart 2") or a name given to the chart.

If the number of columns in the input range does not equal 3 or 1, or the number of rows does not equal the number of data points in the pie chart, the function returns #N/A! error.

A recolored chart will retain the new colors after the function is deleted from the sheet.

```
Option Explicit

  Function SETPIECOLORS(colorRng As Range, chartName As String) As Variant    
      Dim colorArr As Variant
      Dim myChartObject As ChartObject
      Dim i As Long
      Set myChartObject = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName)
'     // Assign RGB decimal color values to array
      If colorRng.Columns.Count = 3 Then
          colorArr = colorRng
'     // Assign RGB hex color values to array
      ElseIf colorRng.Columns.Count = 1 Then
          ReDim colorArr(1 To colorRng.Rows.Count, 1 To 3)
          For i = 1 To colorRng.Rows.Count
              colorArr(i, 1) = "&H" & Left(colorRng(i).Value, 2)
              colorArr(i, 2) = "&H" & Mid(colorRng(i).Value, 3, 2)
              colorArr(i, 3) = "&H" & Mid(colorRng(i).Value, 5, 2)
          Next
      Else
'         // Number of columns in color range not equal to 1 or 3
          SETPIECOLORS = CVErr(xlErrNA)
          Exit Function
      End If
      With myChartObject
          With .Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
              If UBound(colorArr, 1) = .Points.Count Then
'                 // Set the colors of the pie data points
                  For i = 1 To .Points.Count
                      .Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(colorArr(i, 1), colorArr(i, 2), colorArr(i, 3))
                  Next
              Else
'                 // Number of rows in color range does not equal number of data points
                  SETPIECOLORS = CVErr(xlErrNA)
                  Exit Function
              End If
          End With
      End With
      SETPIECOLORS = True
  End Function
```

The function can be installed by copying it into a new module inserted via the Developer / Visual Basic menu accessed from the Excel ribbon.

Comment: Interesting code, thanks. There's also code in the answer to the question I reference in mine. But the question I ask is how to do it without code so this is not an answer.

Comment: Cannot be done without code.

Comment: Thanks Chuff; would you add that comment to the start of your answer and then I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Having added the function to my workbook how do I actually run it? That's got to be obvious but I only seem to be offered macros to run.

Comment: Got it - I needed to add your code to modules not objects in the VBA window. Thanks again