# I need help writing a macro that will check a condition, and then paste a value into a different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, macros

I want to have a macro that will check to see if a specific value exists in a data range, and if that value does exist in that data range, then I want to past a line of text in a different cell. Could you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: what is wrong with a formula in the cell you want to "paste" your string to? please explain the requirement not to have a formula in that specific cell

Comment: The reason I don't the formula to exist in that specific cell is because both the row and column of the desired cell can change, therefore I cant really drag down to apply a formula. The cell I want to paste into can change both in row and column...

Comment: Please don't repeat questions.