# How to Enter Hex Colour Values in Excel?

Tags: windows, colors, microsoft-excel-2013, hexadecimal

I've googled the topic and searched on Super User for a preëxistent answer, and yet I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

What I want to do is simple: just assign a particular colour in the colour palette for cell fill. But I want to do so by using the Hex value of said colour, and it's only giving me the option to enter the RGB or HSL value.

However, this is such a basic option when it comes to colour input modes when it comes to software, I just find it ridiculously hard to believe that no option even exists.

Is this possible—**at all possible**—in Excel 2013?

---

**Not sure if they're needed, but just in case, here's my comp's specs:**

- *Make & Model*: HP Compaq dc5700 SFF Base
- *Operating System*: Windows 7 Professional SP1 x64

Comment: I don't see a way to do this directly in Excel 2013. You could use an [converter](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm) for the hex or use a VBA script. [1](http://superuser.com/questions/585006/can-i-provide-rgb-hex-strings-in-an-excel-worksheet-for-pie-chart-colors-without), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743199/fill-a-cell-with-color-based-on-its-hex-value-in-excel-2013)

Comment: Nah, I don't understand any of that stuff about VBAs. As for the converter deal, I'll just go on color-hex.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I enter Hex colour values in Excel?

This is not possible. Excel uses a version of the [Color Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that only allows generation of custom colours using RGS or HLS.

However you can use an online color converter, such as [Colorizer](http://colorizer.org/nextversion/)
to convert from Hex values to RGB and HSL and then use the results in Excel.

[image]

---

#### What is Colorizer?

> Color picker, calculator and generator with high precision and contrast test. Converts also RGB, HEX, HSL, HSV/HSB, CMYK and CIE-LAB colors and lots of other formats. In the Hex-field, you can write a known color name, too.

---

#### The Color Dialog Box

The Windows SDK provides a "standard" Color Dialog Box to choose colours. Many  programs are built to use this.

[image]

> Displays a modal dialog box that allows the user to choose a specific color value. The user can choose a color from either a set of basic or custom color palettes. Alternatively, the user can generate a color value by modifying the RGB or hue, saturation, luminosity (HSL) color values of the dialog box user interface. The Color dialog box returns the RGB value of the color selected by the user.

Some graphics programs ([GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) for example) that need a more sophisticated colour choosing mechanism provide their own custom dialog.

---

#### Further reading

- [Color Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: How does Colorizer compare to color-hex.com?

Comment: But, ugh, *really now*, this is just pathetic. Most software I come across, no matter how basic, typically **always** has hex value input for colours.

Comment: I've never used color-hex.com. It appears to do some of the same conversions and has all this user's favourite colours and stuff which I would never use. It's up to you to pick the one you like best. There are many more to choose from if you search for "color conversion rgb hex hsl" (12 million+ results ...)

Comment: By the way MS Paint doesn't do HEX either. Neither does LibreOffice Calc (it has RGB, HSB, and CMYK).

Comment: <opens Paint> Hm... Touché. Still, I've noticed it on a lot of basic programmes otherwise, however; so it still surprises me that these programmes do not have it. Seems like a pretty rudimentary, even possibly **required**, feature on any colour selection feature on a computer...

Comment: Windows provides a "standard" dialog to choose colors and most programs are built to use this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Some graphics programs (like Gimp for example) that need a more sophisticated colour choosing mechanism provide their own custom dialog.

Comment: That still doesn't change the fact that I have seen it as an option in relatively basic programmes. But, regardless, alright.

Answer (score 0):

Hex is just RGB in hexadecimal. Split the hex up into 2 digit chunks and convert using a calculator from hex to decimal.   In fact you could probably do that in Excel!

So `00FF00` is `R=0 G=255 B=0`   (`FF=255`)

If you're on windows, you can also use Calc.exe in programmer mode to convert the hex.

You could also use some VBA to take a cell value and convert and alter the cell colour (I imagine).

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the cell or cells you wish to color.
2. Click on the paint bucket to fill in a color.
3. Select "More Colors."
4. Select "Custom."
5. At the bottom of your the the custom panel is "Hex:" Enter Hex code here.